# Laravel Insertion | Why data is posting in a page?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to insert data but the data won't insert. After I click the submit button it just shows the data that I'm trying to insert.

This is my model what looks like:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'quantity', 'description', 'amount', 'category', 'brand', 'status', 'image'];

$inputData = $request->all(); 

if($request->hasfile('image')){
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClienOriginalExtension();
    $filename = time() .'.'. $extension;
    $file->move('uploads/product/', $filename);
    $inputData['image'] = $filename;
}else{
    return $request;
    $product->image = '';
}

return redirect()->route('menu');
```

Comment: Your controller doesn't perform any database insertion at all. Please refer to Laravel document to learn how to insert data into the database:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts

Comment: Hey Andrywin, can you add the code for your form as well? so that we can give a comprehensive answer.